Multithreading causing linear increase in runtime C++
I am designing a fast csv reader for a backtester. For reading the csv file, I read it at first into a string at once. Thereafter I'm creating multiple threads for parsing the data and storing it into a table structure I'm using.
Each thread receives a start and end index, and operates on that part of the string.
When using 1 thread, I get a runtime of 6.5secs. Thereafter, runtime increases almost linearly as I use for eg 2 or 4 threads. I have 8 cores on my system.
I am attaching my worker function as well. The 'lines' attribute is a class attribute that is a vector of string, each string being a line of the csv.
void read_csv_worker(pair<int,int>t){
        auto [start,end] = t;
        vector<pair<string,double>>vec(num_cols - 1); // timestamp also a column but stored explicitly
        string timestamp, curr;
        int curr_index;
        int curr_col;
        stringstream line_stream;

        for(int i=start;i<end;i++){
            timestamp.clear(); 
            line_stream.str(lines[i]);
            line_stream.clear();
            curr_index = 0;
            curr_col = 0;

            while (getline(line_stream, curr, ',')) {
                if (curr_index == timestamp_col_num) 
                    timestamp = curr.substr(1, curr.size()-2);
                else 
                    vec[curr_col++] = {headers[curr_index], stod(curr)}; 
                ++curr_index;
            }
            this->insert(vec, timestamp, i);
        }
    }

Where I create my threads in another class function:
int curr_pos = 0;
        int chunk_size = num_lines/num_threads;
        for(int i=0;i<num_threads-1;i++){
            pair<int,int>t = {curr_pos, curr_pos + chunk_size};
            threads[i] = std::thread([this, t]() {
                read_csv_worker(t);  // Now 'this' is available to the member function
            });
            curr_pos += chunk_size;
        }
        pair<int,int>t = {curr_pos, num_lines};
        threads[num_threads-1] = std::thread([this, t]() {
            read_csv_worker(t); 
        });

        for(int i=0;i<num_threads;i++) threads[i].join();

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you!
Tried slicing the data and passing it to the threads as an argument, as I thought maybe there was contention for the lines class attribute. Didnt help.
Update: Changed all strings to C style strings for efficiency. Apart from improving speed, the code now exhibits the multithreading behaviour as one would normally expect. Can anyone explain why using strings is messing up multithreading?

Spinning up threads takes time and if there is not enough work to do compared to the overhead then it may be a loss, not a win.

Side note : Try replacing std::pair<int,int> with a struct of your own (or just pass two arguments). It may speedup things a little, but it also will make your code more readable. As a rule of thumb, if you use std::pair outside of non-templated code you're using it wrong.

My lines vector has 2e6 lines. In the absence of multithreading it's taking 7 seconds approx for the read. Also I'm just using 2-4 threads currently so overhead of creation of threads must be negligible.

Another side note : instead of pair<int,int>t = {curr_pos, curr_pos + chunk_size}; use std::span<int>

You also forgot to join the resulting vectors into one new output. So consider using std::async instead of std::thread so you can return something from your background threads and use std::future::get, to get your results and combine them.

The vectors are stored in another data structure which the insert function takes care of. It groups together the vector and timestamp for a row and places them at the given index in a raw array already allocated

Post a [mre]. Hard-code the input as 2e6 identical strings. On the way you are very likely to find the culprit yourself.

I suspect there isn't enough work being done on the data inside your threads for the code to be anything other than cache and memory IO bandwidth limited. You really need to profile the code to see where it is spending most of its time to be sure. Intel's VTune is very good for that. I find the MSVC profiler almost useless since its simplistic instrumentation method invariably changes the behaviour that you are trying to measure in highly optimised parallel code.
